# Waiting for gps signal

Tags: java, android

I have an app that gets your location using gps. When you first try to use the gps it takes a while for it to find your location. Is there a way i can stop the app until it has gotten your location?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what do mean by `stop the app`? You can try to show a spinner or a progress dialog till the time you get the location.

Comment: Well i'm thinking like dimming the screen and having a loading animation or something like that, or something like you said.

Comment: Sound right to me. Go ahead with that. There are plenty of questions which can help you achieve that.

Comment: You would need to show some code as to where you are getting the location. Is it in the asynctask ? Before you start getting the location, starte the dialog and when you finish it, dismiss the doialog. Show the relevant code if you want more help :)

Comment: Thanks, i ended up figuring it out.

Answer (score 0):

MBProgessHUD google this. it is a great linrary for showing system interaction